# Using hashtable between multiple functions give me System.Collections.Hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I call a script and pass in about 50 arguments to create a hash table.  in the script I have a function that I call to create the hash table. in this function It calls a few variables from `$env:` that are set and based on this I parse my Hash table to be server specific and return it to the script.  So generate 1 big multiple level hash, then create a new `$hash` from this based on info on the server via keys.  Then this new `$var` is used latter in the scripts to call other scripts and another script passing in this server specific hash, but instead of usable info I end up with `System.Collections.Hashtable`.   Eventually this `$hash` ends up in a scheduled task but by then it is just `System.Collections.Hashtable`.

I can run the code manually in PowerShell and I get a hash table and I can manipulate it the issue arises when I start trying to use it.

Second issue is I inharited these scripts and they are being called by another method so troubleshooting, and getting logging has been a real pain.  I do have a bunch of log calls that end up in a file not sure if the log functionality is causing some issues on top as well, to what really is in the `$hash`.

My scripts are code signed, is there an issue with this?

If I call a function, or a ps1 can I pass the `$hash` to it?  Is there something special I have to do?

I basically just want pass the `$hash` with all the info:

```
foo-dostuff $hash
```

Beginning to think I can't.

Comment: Instead of *describing* your code, why don't you *show* us your code? A [mcve] to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're casting/coercing this hashtable to a string. A hashtable's tostring() method essentially just outputs the typename:

```
(@{name = 'whatev'}).ToString()
```

Check to see if one of the function parameters where you're using the hashtable is of type `[string]`.

Answer (score 0):

I know I needed to provide some code but the sheer amount of code I'm working with isn't easy to just post online. I do apologize.

The key thing I figured out is the previous writer of the code is leveraging Windows Task scheduler to run code in a service account context due to special permissions.

The issue I was having was trying to pass a variable with Hash data in it to this scheduled task.  I ended up outputting the hash to a file then importing it again.

So Don't try and use a Hash table with Scheduled tasks.